# who signs the certificate (Root CA or an intermediate authority?

Tags: certificates

Are certificates issued by a Trusted Root CA signed by the private key from the Root CA or rather by an intermediate certificate ?

thx

Answer (score 3):

If the certificates are directly issued by the Root CA (which is usually only Intermediate CA certs) then they are signed using the Root CA private key.  The certificates typically issued to servers or users are signed with an Intermediate CA private key one or two levels down from the root.